# Problema al acceder a GoogleCalendar con mi app .net C#

Tags: c#, google-calendar, google-oauth

Tengo un método simple que agrega al calendario de google eventos, funciona a la perfección desde localhost, agrega eventos, pregunta al usuario con las credenciales por primera vez si quiere dejar que la app acceda a su calendario y todo bárbaro hasta ahí, ahora la app va a salir a producción y cuando hosteamos en amazon ec2 me deja de funcionar...
Codigo del access token generado automaticamente por la credential...

```
     "access_token": "ya29.Il-zB1VbH4-OZfNPGntJ0DZU3vmdP3lnVR2_QzOra6hkRGHNT6AjqXwGhMinLg8s9yBlSQOxA67HWEC_jRLIqBOYnB4JDuTQDBVolpWUVe1l8u_q1-pJ8j56HUcrva0Zyg",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "Issued": "2019-12-04T01:08:50.425-03:00",
  "IssuedUtc": "2019-12-04T04:08:50.425Z",
  "refresh_token": "1//0hb0RvjGB-oS5CgYIARAAGBESNwF-L9IruFMH-1IwILK2OAyib5XokJKg5VbaLbZCMqQfLxDJaqNt2IzGKig_TxUPJ08ThIyIwtE",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
```

Codigo del Json Credentials:

```
{
  "web": {
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "client_id": "28564481859-f8ae4n6jt34eas0uug1pcifdt8jq53tt.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "***************",
    "project_id": "quickstart-1574989503184",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
  }}
```

Codigo del metodo de evento y calendario:

```
 //GOOGLE CALENDAR

        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };

        private void AddToGoogleCalendar()
        {

            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
               // Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,

            });

            var ev = new Event();
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
            start.DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 12, 19, 14, 30, 00);

            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
            end.DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 12, 19, 16, 30, 00);

            ev.Location = "Avenida Fuerza Aerea 4209, Cordoba";
            ev.Start = start;
            ev.End = end;
            ev.Summary = "Titulo de Prueba";
            ev.Description = "Descripcion de Prueba";
            var calendarId = "primary";
            Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
}
```

A alguien le paso algo parecido ? Estare necesitando definir algo en la consola de google ? no hice la verificacion porque me pedia cosas demasiado puntuales y creo que no eran necesarias para esto... estare obligado a pasar por esa verificacion ?

[image: Pantalla de consentimiento donde puse el dominio del hosting y nada mas porque si no me pide verificacion, sera que tengo que pasar por la verificacion si o si ? tenia entendido que no!]

Comment: Yo en tu lugar no dejaría los client_secret y demás info privada a la vista de todos. Creo que es importante. Estuvo bien que nos mostraras qué hiciste, pero ten cuidado siempre con tus datos.

Comment: La api es gratis y los cambio todos los dias... por eso no me gaste en ocultarlos, pero gracias por tu consejo

Comment: Está bien tu explicación y todo... pero... ¿Cual es el error? Te tiene que estar generando un error de lo contrario no sabríamos cómo ayudarte.

Comment: Directamente al ejecutar el metodo se traba el sistema y me da error 404... nunca se carga el evento en el calendario... pero es rarisimo porque local SI me anda perfecto... no se que me falta! lamentablemente mi conocimiento es limitado para hacer un try catch de una api de google a ese nivel

Comment: Creo que te falta decirle desde la consola de google desde que dominios está permitido acceder al calendar desde la consola de google. Fíjate bien en el mensaje de error por si te dice que debes usar una cuenta de email autorizada, localhost te lo permite

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, lo pudiste resolver? Saludos.....